# How to test activity containing WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have activity which contains WebView loading some url from Internet, I'd like to ensure that expected HTML is present on WebView, how to get this content?
I know its possible using JavaScript trick, but I don't like to put tricks in production code...

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking. If you have an Activity with a layout that contains a WebView you should be able to call loadUrl() on your WebView reference and the page should load inside your webview, be it testing or otherwise. No need for any special javascript on your page

Comment: @Tim - I think you missed the point of the question.  See answer from Michaelg.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for your WebView. Then you can override shouldInterceptRequest and/or shouldOverrideUrlLoading. This will let you know about all of the network traffic (page loads, Ajax requests, plus more mundane things like images and CSS being loaded) to the page. You could then log this on a debug or info setting, so it is only being logged in development, not in the production build (assuming you set the log levels appropriately for a release build.) You could also build unit test assertions based on the info provided in these methods. Overriding these two methods can also provide you hooks for loading test pages for unit testing purposes. Similarly, you can create a custom [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) for your WebView. You can override its onConsoleMessage to direct JS logging and warnings/errors to your normal Android log.